# Uninstalling VS2012 hangs on system restore point

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, system-restore, visual-studio-2012, windows-defender

I am trying to uninstall VS2012 on my dev VM and have tried the following so far:

-Turned off Windows Defender completely
-Disabled restore point creation in System Settings
-Used the cmd prompt ...vs-premium.exe /uninstall /force
-Deleted any extra c++ distributable packages

BUT the uninstall still hangs on "Creating System Restore Points.."
Is there any other way I can make this happen?

Comment: Have you checked the installation log which contains more verbose information.  Can you manually create a restore point?

Comment: @Ramhound I did create the restore point manually, however, the forced uninstall still tries to create it itself. I did solve the problem by removing all the tools and duplicate distibutable c++ packages until uninstall worked

Comment: You should submit what you did as an answer then.  You should know there are multiple seperate versions of the C++ redistributable though, so they were unlikely, duplicate installations.

Comment: @Ramhound You are right but I suspect it was one of the 77 components that caused the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no other than @Ramhound responded and I fixed the problem, I thought I should post it as an answer. I couldn't exactly pinpoint what the problem was, but I have a good idea of the root causes. I followed these steps and successfully removed VS2010 and 2012 and installed 2013 successfully.

1) Removed C++ redistributable from Programs and Features. There were many versions of it including the same one for x64 and x86. Removed almost all of them.

2) Then I manually removed some of the extra VS tools that came with the initial install. I deleted about 7-8.

3) Instead of going straight to the forced uninstall, I ran a repair on the original setup file. I think this was the step that saved me after removing all the packages and tools from Steps 1 and 2.

4) Created a restore point manually

5) Turned off Windows Defender and the System Restore Point creation. I don't think this helped much to be honest as the uninstall still said 'Creating System Restore point'

6) Then I started the forced uninstall and it was successful.

A good place to start is removing all the unnecessary VS tools that you don't use.